# How can I use the `identify` command to find out *only* the file type?

Tags: imagemagick, file-type

I want to use the `identify` command (from *ImageMagick*) to determine a file's type.

The sample command

```
identify -quiet 'Sample File.gif'
```

will list several lines. Is there a short and simple way to obtain just the string `GIF`?

Comment: The `file` command is more versatile than `identify` but is even more noisy.

Comment: The `file --extension -b 'Sample File.jpg'` command will return `jpeg/jpg/jpe/jfif`. Whereas I want a _single_ `jpeg` output.

Comment: I did say it is noisy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `%m` [percent escape](https://imagemagick.org/script/escape.php) to get just the file **m**agic:

```
identify -quiet -format '%m\n' 'Sample File.gif'
```

Comment: Thanks. I think that the _ImageMagick_ tools are so powerful, but also very little known and documented! :)